# What is the life expectancy of a Bolian?

Tags: star-trek

[Bolians.](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bolian) A Federation race, but sadly no main character in any of the series was a Bolian, so they didn't get much screen time.

**How long does the average Bolian live for?** Preferably looking for answers in the TV shows or movies, but failing that books and video games will work.

Comment: What about technical/writers' manuals?

Comment: @Junuxx If one has a reference to it, then by all means post it as an answer. Forgot about those!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TV Canon

**We don't know.** At no point in any of the shows (or films) is the lifecycle of the average Bolian described. For all we know, they could be as short-lived as the Okampa or as long-lived as the Vulcans.

### EU Canon

**We don't know.** There are scattered references in some of the EU books to elderly Bolians, but again there's no indication of how many years it takes to be considered elderly.

There are mentions that a Bolian can take upward of 5 years to become sufficiently comfortable with a partner to propose marriage and that polygamous marriages of more than 5-6 partners are surprisingly rare. This would at least give us a lower bound of 50+ years but again, we can't really tell if the upper bound is 75 or 750.

Comment: "We don't know" isn't really the answer. Because there are no Bolians, and they don't have any life expectancy at all. There's nothing for us to know or not know. A Bolian's life expectancy is undefined, not unknown.

Comment: @MikeScott - I'm guessing the writers know. Hence "we don't know" rather than "no-one knows"

Comment: I very much doubt that the writers know. They would only know if it had ever been important, at which point it would have made it onto screen. As it is, they will make it up if they ever need it for a plot they're working on.

Comment: @MikeScott - There are many trek species whose lifecycles are known, but where the details never made it onto the screen.